# Is foreign_key option has to be put as the options of belongs_to and has_many at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am writing some Ruby-on-Rails code and I have some question about the usage of `foreign_key` in a belongs_to/has_many relationship.
I have two models, one is `Slogan` and the other is `User`. The relation between the two is one slogan corresponds to only one user(belongs_to) and a user can have many slogan records(has_many). The code of two models are listed below

```
# slogan.rb
class Slogan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :author_id
end
```

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :slogans
end
```

For the convenience of maintenance and semantics, I change the association name on slogan to author(it should be user originally) and change the foreign_key to `author_id`.

And my question is that should I also add `foreign_key` option in user model if I also want to all slogans that he/she has from user record ?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add anything. But you can take use of bi-directional association in Rails.
Active Record provides the `:inverse_of` option so you can explicitly declare bi-directional associations:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, inverse_of: 'writer'
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'Author', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

By using this, you can use as follow:

```
a = Author.first
b = a.books.first
a.first_name == b.writer.first_name # => true
a.first_name = 'David'
a.first_name == b.writer.first_name # => true
```

For more info refer: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks your answering. But I want to know if under my code, should the foreign_key be added at both associations?

Comment: But when I only add `foreign_key` option at Slogan. I can find the author of one slogan record but I can't not find all the slogan records of a user. The error messages is listed below
[error message picture](https://imgur.com/ajIziDd)

Answer (score 0):

In your error message, I see the id is `user_id` and not `author_id`. You can either change the id in the table to `author_id` or remove the `foreign_key` from the slogan model. The foreign_key constraint is telling your `Slogan` model that is should be looking for a `author_id` column in the db. It can't find that column because it's called `user_id`.

Comment: but i already add author_id in my Slogan table, I don't know what's wrong with that.

Comment: In the error that you posted, it shows user_id. What does your db scheme file look like? Also, what does your slogan controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

You **must add** `foreign_key` option in your `User` model.

From the document https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference:

> By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign
>   key on the other model is the name of this model with the suffix _id
>   added.

So if you don't add `foreign_key` option, Rails assumes you have an `user_id` column on `slogans` table, it is reason why you have [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mUML.jpg).